# Change image_tag to button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, button-to

I'm trying to figure out how to change this code:

```
%li.input.optional= link_to_remove_association image_tag('minus.png', {:alt => "#{t('blabla.remove_model', model: t('activerecord.models.template_instance_right.one'))}"}), f
```

to use a button instead. It's the first time I use Rails so I'm a bit lost.

I tried:

```
=button_to('Remove', {:alt => "#{t('blabla.remove_model', model: t('activerecord.models.template_instance_right.one'))}"})
```

which does display the button but it doesn't delete the record.

I think I need to use `link_to_remove_association` but I don't know how to combine it with a button essentially. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `image_tag` with `button_tag` tag:

```
%li.input.optional= link_to_remove_association button_tag('Remove', {:alt => "#{t('blabla.remove_model', model: t('activerecord.models.template_instance_right.one'))}"})
```